How to implement dynamic databases in spring boot?
I am working on a Spring Boot application that needs to handle dynamic database connections based on API requests. Each request may target a different database, and the database properties (URL, username, password, etc.) are stored in a separate centralized database.
By default, the application is connected to one database for general purposes, but if a request specifies a different database, the connection should switch dynamically.
I have previously used multiple schemas within a single database to manage different tenants. However, as the application scales, I plan to distribute tenants across multiple databases, which makes dynamic connection management essential.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
